# Decide whether the following set X is finite or infinite. If infinite, prove whether it is countable or uncountable. If finite, find |X|.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$X = \{(m, n) ∈ \mathbb{Z} × \mathbb{Z} \mid m + n = 3\}$

Claim: X is infinite and countable.

Rewriting $X$:

$X= \{\left(m,3-m\right) \mid m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Consider the function $f(m):\:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(m)=(m,3-m)$

**Injective:**

Suppose $f(m_1) = f(m_2)$

$\rightarrow (m_1,3-m_1) = (m_2,3-m_2)$

$\rightarrow m_1=m_2$ and $3-m_1=3-m_2$

$\rightarrow m_1 = m_2$ as required.

**Surjective**

Here is where I'm stuck. How can I prove that such a function is surjective?

Any feedback would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it is surjective in $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$? Is there an $m$ such that $f(m) = (1,1)$?

Comment: I've read in my textbook that to prove that something is countable, you have to form a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. So I though maybe I can prove its countable by forming a bijection. I think my though process is wrong though considering what you've said.

Comment: No that is correct, I am just trying to understand where you're stuck. Certainly your function is not surjective for $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ but it is for the set $X$ right? So you really mean the function $f: \mathbb N \to X$. Can you show that for any $x \in X$ there is a corresponding $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(m) = x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. You should first modify your argument to show that the function $f: {\Bbb Z} \to X$ defined by $f(m) = (m, 3-m)$ is a bijection. This will show that $X$ is infinite. If you already know that $\Bbb Z$ is countable, this will also prove that $X$ is countable. If you need to prove that $\Bbb Z$ is countable, you could try to find a bijection $g : {\Bbb Z} \to {\Bbb N}$ sending the non negative integers to the even natural numbers and the negative numbers to the odd numbers (there are other ways to find a bijection, this is just one possibility).